# How to pervent Edittext value To start with (.) and contains two (.) in a row?

Tags: java, android

in my situation i have EditText to get the value for my math operation , So i have set inputType of this EditText to **android:inputType="numberSigned"** also add this tag
**android:digits="1234567890."** to only get numbers and (.) because my value can be Double , but i don't want the user to start his value with (.) like ".58" also use two (.) in row like "2..5" so i have add the code below but unfortunately it's not working for me. also I'm using TextChangedListener for my EditText.

```
    public static String trimString(String string) {
    if (string.startsWith(".")) {
        return string.replace(".", "");
    } else if (string.contains(",") & string.contains("..")) {
        return string.replace(",", "").replace("..", ".");
    } else {
        return string;
    }
}
```

TextChangedListener code:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    if (isEmpty(editTextAmount)) {
         tvResult.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0033"));
         tvResult.setText(R.string.error_text);
      } else {
         String firstData = autoCompleteTextView.getText().toString();
         String secondData = autoCompleteTextView2.getText().toString();
         String amount = trimString(editTextAmount.getText().toString());
         doMath(firstData, secondData, amount);
      }

   }
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `inputType="number"`?

Comment: @SagarBalyan i did before , because if i use number user cant put Double values in editText using (.) and i should use ' android:digits="1234567890." ' and it would be the same thing.

Comment: What problem are you facing with your trimString() method?

Comment: @SagarBalyan The problem is when i type (.) the app will crash with this Error : '     java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0 '

Comment: Try writing your logic inside `afterTextChanged` instead of `onTextChanged`

Comment: @SagarBalyan I just did and it worked mate , Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to Help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you also have another problem. if you use "numberSigned" as the input type you cant use "." character and if you add `android:digits="1234567890."` there will be no limit of how many times the "." char will appear in your EditText. it can be

> ..

or

> ..58

or

> 2..5

or even

> 35.67.12

so you see, it's not a ***number*** any more.

You can use `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` instead of `numberSigned`.
This way you only can call "." once in a number (as  numbers should be ) and as there is no "," in Decimal numbers user can not use that key even by mistake. so you are already two problems ahead.

As for the "." character at the start of the input, I personally see no problem in that. It is totally OK to have `.7` instead of `0.7` but if you want to prevent it you can simply check if it start with "." or not and replace "." with "0."

in conclusion replace the `android:inputType="numberSigned"` with `android:inputType="numberDecimal"`; delete the `android:digits="1234567890."` and you are good to go.

Comment: Your are a life and time saver , Tnx a lot!

Comment: I haven't verified, but for some countries the comma is the decimal separator so `there is no ","` might not be true in all cases